# Render without using _quarto.yml

Tags: quarto

In a website project context, the settings in **_quarto.yml** is used during `quarto render document.qmd` by default. How do I skip using **_quarto.yml** for a specific document in the folder?

I don't see anything obvious in `quarto render --help`, but I am thinking something like `quarto render --disable-config document.qmd` which should only use the yaml metadata specified within that document.

Comment: Similar question at https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/5224.

Comment: Yes, Running in different [profiles](https://quarto.org/docs/projects/profiles.html) sounds interesting: `quarto render --profile production,advanced`.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need `_quarto.yml`for render any document.